# Изменить формат даты в js

Tags: javascript, дата, simpledateformat

Получаю дату с бд в формате `dd.mm.yyyy` надо для пользователя вывести в формате `dd MM yyyy` т.е месяц надо вывести прописью будь это октябрь, ноябрь и т.д и убрать точки соответственно. Погуглил но ничего такого не нашел строка формате

```
let date = new Date('14.10.2022')
```

выдает ошибку `Invalid Date`

```
let date = Date.parse(14.10.2022)
```

тоже не работает.
Подскажите как получить дату в формате `14 Октября 2022`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

UPD Добавил..

```js
function dt(d){
 d = d.split('.');
 return d[0] + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleString('ru',{month:'long'}) + ' ' + d[2];
}
console.log(dt('14.10.2022'))

function dt2(d) {
  d = d.split('.').reverse().join('-');
  return new Date(d).toLocaleString('ru', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  });
}
console.log(dt2('14.10.2022'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`moment js` в помощь, чтобы прочитать нужный формат через него `moment('10.12.2022', 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')` к примеру.

Также там еще еще много всяких преобразований

Answer (score 1):

Несколько решений:

```
const arr = '01.10.2022'.split('.')
const date = new Date(`${arr[2]}-${arr[1]}-${arr[0]}`)
//const date = new Date(2022, 9, 1); // 2022-10-01

const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
const str = date.getDate() + ' ' + month + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
console.log(str);
```

1 октябрь 2022

```
const options = {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
};
const arr = '01.10.2022'.split('.')
const date = new Date(`${arr[2]}-${arr[1]}-${arr[0]}`)
//const date = new Date(2022, 9, 1); // 2022-10-01
const str = date.toLocaleString('default', options);
console.log(str);
```

1 октября 2022 г.

Ну под себя уж сами переработаете:)

Comment: Бро у меня формат даты `dd.mm.yyyy` и как я описывал выше из-за такого формата не могу распарсить дату

Comment: Поправил. Думал это уж можно проделать :)

Answer (score 1):

Так как не являюсь разработчиком на JS, могу предложить костыльный способ. Превращайте дату в string и работайте дальше с ним.

```
const data = "14.10.2022"
const splitData = data.split(".")
console.log(splitData) //[ '14', '10', '2022' ]
//splitData[2] = ГОД
//splitData[1] = месяц
//splitData[0] = день

// далее использую ответ Виктора:

const date = new Date(splitData[2], splitData[1], splitData[0]); // 2022-10-01

const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
const str = date.getDate() + ' ' + month + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
console.log(str);
```